# Attempting to JIT compile method (....) while running with --aot-only

Tags: xamarin, compilation, jit, xamarin.forms

I am getting this exception when I process a WCF request from my Xamarin.Forms app:

**"Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper runtime-invoke) :runtime_invoke_bool_Nullable`1 (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)' while running with --aot-only.
See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.\n"**

Please, how could I fix this? I have checked the server side but it seems ok.

The rest of WCF requests are working fine and this only happens in devices (not in simulator).

This is happening **only in iOS**, in Android it works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: iOS does not allow JIT'ing, everything must be AOT compiled... An Apple restriction for all apps (except javascript JIT'ing within their Nitro JavaScript engine).

Comment: @Fran_gg7 Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score -3):

iOS does not allow dynamic code generation / JIT'ing, everything must be AOT compiled... An Apple security restriction for all apps, JIT'ing within their own Nitro JavaScript engine is an exception to that rule.

Xamarin explains it very well in the link that is provided via the exception:

> No Dynamic Code Generation
>
> Since the iPhone's kernel prevents an
>   application from generating code dynamically Mono on the iPhone does
>   not support any form of dynamic code generation. These include:
>
> The System.Reflection.Emit is not available.
>
> No support for System.Runtime.Remoting.
>
> No support for creating types dynamically (no
>   Type.GetType ("MyType`1")), although looking up existing types
>   (Type.GetType ("System.String") for example, works just fine).
>
> Reverse callbacks must be registered with the runtime at compile time.

Ref: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#No_Dynamic_Code_Generation

Comment: Ok thank you for this info, but my question is...how to workaround this? thanks a lot mate :)

Comment: @SushiHangover, I am getting same error in My iOS Application. Which is build using Xamarin.Forms 3.0 + EFCore 2.0. Do you have any solution for it?

Comment: @PavanVParekh I would imagine it is due to EFCore 2.0, you can check on the GitHub repo issue list to see if iOS usage is still broken